# Prevent access to files from Apache without .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

(LAMP server configuration)

As a workaround for another problem, I need PHP to be able to access local files, but prevent these files from being served over http by Apache.

Normally, I would just use .htaccess to accomplish this, however due to institutional restrictions, I cannot. I also can't touch php.ini, although I can use php_ini_set within php.

As a creative solution, I thought that if php executes as its own linux user (not as apache) I could use normal chown's and chmod's to accomplish this.

Again, the goal is simply to have a directory of files that apache will not display, but php can access.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a thought. Set the permissions on the files to be inaccessible to even the owner, then when PHP needs them, [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) then, read them, then `chmod()` them back to inaccessible.

Comment: chmod them in php? This could work.

relevant documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_chmod.asp

Comment: love the hack! Works perfectly.

`//change permissions to allow access
chmod($full_filename, 0600);
   
$htmlstring = file_get_contents($full_filename);

//change permissions to reset access
chmod($full_filename, 0100);`

Comment: You might want to use PHP's `fileperms()` function to store the old permissions before changing them, then use those when you revert so you don't mess anything up.

Answer (score 5):

Put the files outside of your web accessible root (`DocumentRoot`), but keep them accessible via PHP.

Suggestion:

```
/sites
/sites/my.site.com
/sites/my.site.com/data  // <-- data goes here
/sites/my.site.com/web   // <-- web root is here
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but since there are other restrictions, this might not be possible.

Comment: .htaccess with a RewriteRule to block all non PHP files? it's a bit iffy if you can't access the server configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this (as suggested in root awnser) is what i'll have to do if nothing else works. I hesitate to do this because it will result in significant changes to my codebase.

Comment: Why does the path of the files 'significantly change the codebase'? Functionality doesn't change. With any luck you only have to change one settings file.

Comment: It's an inherited codebase with lots of hard-coded paths. For the time being, i just need to get it working to debug, etc... I appreciate the answer. This is definitely the textbook answer, and the one I will implement as soon as i have some time to re-write the bad code.