# how to prevent access to directory without htaccess in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have already read this [Prevent access to files from Apache without .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590560/prevent-access-to-files-from-apache-without-htaccess) It is not my case.

**Note: I have not allowed to use .htaccess**

I have a url like http://example.com/ its take me to index page and its fine.

When the url is http://example.com/ajax_scripts/ here **ajax_scripts** is a directory where server shows **403 Forbidden**.

But I want to show my own custom Error page that is located in http://example.com/error_pages/error_403.php

When User want to access this http://example.com/ajax_scripts/ user should redirect to http://example.com/error_pages/error_403.php

How can I do it without **.htaccess?**

**Update:** There will be some other text instead of **ajax_scripts**

**Update 2:** What about if I have errors **401, 403, 404 and 405** and want to redirect them in their specific error pages

Comment: If you restrict access to /ajax_scripts/ then your ajax scripts would't be able to access it neither.

Comment: But I want to show my custom error_page that I mention above

Comment: Look out: http://papermashup.com/create-an-error-page-to-handle-all-errors-with-php/ and http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-htaccess-to-redirect-custom-error-pages

Answer (score 2):

It is apache behavior, nothing can be done by php.

You could change the apache config by:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error_pages/error_403.php
```

Comment: I have no access to it. :(

Comment: You can place that on a .htaccess file and it should work equaly

Comment: I have mention in my question **Note: I have not allowed to use .htaccess**

Comment: As I mention in my Question that **Note: I have not allowed to use .htaccess** mean my server not allow .htaccess. The use of .htaccess is disabled in httpd.conf

Comment: @SohailAhmad yes you have however I was generally point that besides apache that runs from .htaccess as well, that's exactly why it was a comment and not an answer. if you cannot access the htaccess and the httpd conf then your only option is make a php that gets the data and place the data on a protected folder.